# 1px border on image leaves weird white gap on top and right of image

Tags: html, css, resolution

As you can see on the screenshot (and maybe you will be able to reproduce from the code snippet depending on your computer), there is a very annoying white gap that I don't know where is coming from. This is not the issue about the gap at the bottom due to display inline property.

This gap does not show at all on my Mac but does show on my Lenovo and Asus laptops. Also shows up on Edge and Firefox.

[image]

```css
img{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
```

Comment: Try going into dev tools, add `transform: translate(1px, 0)` to your element, and then remove the `transform` property. If this makes the gap disappear, you are unfortunately dealing with a rendering bug.

Comment: That exact line does not fix it, however I understand the idea and I do believe is a bug, it is also showing on my other 2 computers except on my macbook.

Comment: No repro on Firefox Nightly 85.0a1 or Chrome 87.0.4280.66, Linux or Android. Do you have a high DPI screen?

Comment: This is what it looks like [on Firefox Nightly 91.0a1](//i.stack.imgur.com/LfRJT.png) ([scaled up](//i.stack.imgur.com/daptR.png)) using the same 400 % zoom. Still no repro. Does this still occur? (Again) Do you have a high DPI screen?

Comment: Yes this still occurs, it's 3 different screens, one high DPI which would be the MAC the other two low-medium.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when height is not fixed like in

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Resolved this by replacing `border: 1px solid` by `outline: 1px solid` with `box-sizing: border-box`.